# Maven "JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE"

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu, linux-mint

I had the following command working fine with OpenJDK

```
mvn clean install
```

I then uninstalled OpenJDK and installed Oracle JDK 8, and now when I run `mvn clean install`

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This
>   environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME
>   should point to a JDK not a JRE

I'm running Linux Mint 19, I did run into a few Stackoverflow questions related to the issue. Most where related to Windows and some that were related to Linux. The Linux ones recommended to run

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

but in my case I get

> There is only one alternative in link group java (providing
>   /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java Nothing to
>   configure.

Any idea how I can make `mvn clean install` work again?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I had accidentally pasted the wrong thing in my question. I fixed it. `mvn clean install` says `The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
`

Comment: Java home should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jdk` - check that it exists

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't see jdk. I have `bin lib src.zip
COPYRIGHT LICENSE THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
include man THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
javafx-src.zip  README.html jre release
`

Comment: Do you have a directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin` that contains among others `java` and `javac`? If yes, set JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.

Comment: @Henry I do, how do I set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Yes I do not think you have a JDK installed - try again

Comment: I just uninstalled Oracle Java and installed `openjdk-11-jdk` using apt. I am sure it's installed. But Maven still gives the same error

Comment: to set an evironment variable in the current shell use something like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. To set it permanently check the conventions of your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 3):

May be java path configuration missing. You can follow this steps:

1. Create or export JAVA_HOME="JDK directory" . Ex. "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65**"
2. Create or export Path variable for PATH="JDK Bin DIrectory" . Ex. "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin**"
3. Run command **java -version** from your terminal.Check it is correct or not.

Then configure maven. follow these steps : 
You can try to install maven globaly. you can skip these steps if already configured.just for check run **mvn --version** command for checking maven is installed correctly.

1. Download maven from [maven download link](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. Create or export M2_HOME="MAVEN ROOT LOCATION". Ex. : **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\apache-maven-3.5.2**
3. Create or export MAVEN bin folder location to PATH variable. For example: **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin**
4. Open terminal or cmd and run mvn --version to confirm maven is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the link to setup the **JAVA_HOME for Linux** -

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2532/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t.html

**Setting up Maven again** :

https://maven.apache.org/install.html

**check whether the `mvn -v` command is working or not..**

Then execute other commands with mvn..

***Thanks :)***

Answer (score 0):

**For mac or ubuntu users**

Make sure java is installed, if you have installed java 1.7

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7 -f)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or java 1.8, change the version accordingly.

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 -f)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now check,

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

This should be pointing to correct java version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this for future me's bc after all the links in StackOverflow, the solution was to check `mvn.cmd` file on `C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin`...

On [line 52](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5iMd.png) it sets the JDK, but it didn't had the "`/bin`" where my `OpenJDK 15` stored the **java.exe**

This fixed the issue on Windows 11 but it could serve as an idea to check on other OS. Hope that it helps!